# differential equations with 2 independent variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If ${\Phi(x)=z}$ and ${v(z) = y(x)\Psi(x)}$ then how would you solve the equation

$\frac{\Phi''}{\Phi'} = 2\frac{\Psi'}{\Psi}$

Answer (score 0):

A quick integration of both sides reveals that:

$$ \Phi^{(1)} = C \Psi^2$$
Using the definition of $\Phi$:

$$ v(\Phi(x)) = y(x) \Psi(x) $$

Squaring this equation, we see that:

$$ C v(\Phi(x))^2 = y(x)^2 \Phi^{(1)}(x)$$

You then have an ODE in only a single variable $\Phi(x)$ to solve.

Edit:  I might not be answering the question you actually want answered.  If this is a general version of a more specific problem, it'd be handy to know the specific problem.